# Django help_text

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I would like to put some help text in this form.

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
      alternative_id = forms.CharField(max_length = 60, required = False, help_text = 'Valid wildcard search is in the format *XX, *XX*, XX*')
```

However it does not appear on the page. Is it because I may need a template tag somewhere?

**EDIT**: I have this written in my template.

```
<div id="location_header">Search for Items</div>
<div id="form_container">
<form action="." method="post">
        <fieldset class="model">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {{ alternative_id.help_text }}
        </fieldset>
        <div id="form_footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" >
        </div>

</form>
</div>
```

Help text still does not appear. Is there a way to write a help text, while allowing django to generate a form?

Comment: You probably want {{ form.alternative_id.help_text }}

Comment: is alternative_id in the response context ?

Comment: @Tommaso No but I thought I did not need to do that. In this case how would I want to write it?

Comment: {{ alternative_id.help_text }} is useless if you don't have alternative_id explicitly defined in the response context, anyway form.alternative_id is the way to go as suggested by StephenPaulger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting `{{ form.as_p }}` (or just `{{ form }}`) in your template should display the help_text without additional code, provided that you have `form` in your context (but I suppose you do if you get the field on your page).

Answer (score 24):

Step 1.  Read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Step 2.  Customize.  Here are the rules.

> Within this loop, {{ field }} is an
>   instance of BoundField. BoundField
>   also has the following attributes,
>   which can be useful in your templates:
>
> {{ field.label }} The label of the
>   field, e.g. E-mail address.
>
> {{ field.label_tag }} The field's
>   label wrapped in the appropriate HTML
>    tag, e.g. E-mail address
>
> {{ field.html_name }} The name of the
>   field that will be used in the input
>   element's name field. This takes the
>   form prefix into account, if it has
>   been set.
>
> {{ field.help_text }} Any help text
>   that has been associated with the
>   field.
>
> {{ field.errors }} Outputs a  containing any
>   validation errors corresponding to
>   this field. You can customize the
>   presentation of the errors with a {%
>   for error in field.errors %} loop. In
>   this case, each object in the loop is
>   a simple string containing the error
>   message.

Comment: @Shehzad009: Your code looks nothing like the example in the Django documentation.  Please read the supplied link.

Comment: Of course, because by the looks of things, does not look like I can use form.as_p to generate the form.

Answer (score 1):

I see something is missing in your snipped, if the ItemForm instance is passed in template as {{ form }} try 
`{{ form.alternative_id.help_text }}`.. as the docs says in the @S.Lott answer.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where we use Django *inlineformset_factory* for parent/child scenario and the `formset` fields are laid out manually (looping through the form fields), the `help_text` won't get displayed in the usual way for child model fields even where the `help_text` has been added in model field definition.

In such cases we may simply add a reference to the `help_text` like this:

```
{% for form in some_formset.forms %}
        # ...
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}    # Loop thru' form fields
        {% if field.name == 'field1' %}   # field1 has `help_text` assigned in model
            {{ field }} {{ field.help_text }}
        {% else %}
            {{ field }}
        {% endif %}
        # ...
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Tested and is working (*with hardly any additional codes*).